# Solr File type definition without Analyzer tag in schema.xml?

Tags: solr, synonym, fieldtype

I see a Solr field type definition in [Solr synonym setting for two Chinese characters 台,臺](http://mpleader.pixnet.net/blog/post/175188510-solr-%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87%E5%90%8C%E7%BE%A9%E5%AD%97%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A)

```
<fieldType name="text_zh" class="solr.TextField">
   <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>    
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer class="jeasy.analysis.MMAnalyzer" />
</fieldType>
```

I am confused about two places:

1. MMAnalyzer is not within any analyzer tag, what does this mean?
2. StandardTokenizerFactory and MMAnalyzer both will tokenize text, the former does 1-gram, wherease the latter does dictionary-lookup actually. Who comes first and who come last? Don't they conflict with each other? What will the end result be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to be a mistake. The correct usage must want to have different analysis chains for indexing and for querying.

This means the second analyzer should be:

```
<analyzer type="query" class="jeasy.analysis.MMAnalyzer" />
```

That way when text is indexed, it will use StandardTokenizerFactory and apply synonyms. But during query, it will **only** do MMAAnalyzer. You can test that in Admin UI's Analysis screen by using both Index and Query text boxes and compare the processing steps.